# jsp access nested attribute of class via dot notation

Tags: java, jsp

I have two classes and two pages found below:

My question is how do I access the attributes of HelloModel from HelloView to have them displayed in helloName.jsp .  The dot notation is not working out for me, and I am not sure if this would require a custom tag to perform this type of work.  I had been doing a fair amount of icefaces lately and assumed it would be similar.   It is not working out in the sense it cannot find the property `hm.name`

```
class HelloView  
{  
    private HelloModel hm;
    public String getAttribute()  
    {  
       return hm.getName();  
    }

    //getters / setters
}  


class HelloModel  
{  
   private String name;  
   //getters / setters
}    

hello.jsp  
<form action="helloName.jsp" method="post" name="form">
        Hello enter your name!

        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >  

helloName.jsp  
<body>

        <jsp:useBean id="hello" class="HelloView" scope="page">
         <jsp:setProperty property="hm.name" name="hello"/>
        </jsp:useBean>
        Thank you <%=hello.getHelloModel()%> 
</body>
```

Comment: If JSP EL is similar to JSF, then hm.name in jsp tag would call getHm().getName()? Why do you need getter in HelloView then? Also please provide names of getters and setters.

Comment: @JMelnik UI should not directly access my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `<jsp:useBean>`s.

Based on the information and code given so far, that would look something like this:

```html
<jsp:useBean id="hm" class="HelloModel" scope="page">
    <jsp:setProperty name="hm" property="name" />
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean id="hello" class="HelloView" scope="page">
    <jsp:setProperty name="hello" property="hm" value="${hm}" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

The first one creates `HelloModel` and sets the request parameter `name` as a property of it (it should have a `public void setName(String name)` method). The second one creates `HelloView` and sets the `HelloModel` as `hm` property of it (it should have a `public void setHm(HelloModel hm)` method).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, `<jsp:useBean>` follows a different MVC approach than normal JSF and JSP/Servlets. It's recommend to **not** use it. Also, classes should be inside a package or it will fail on most servers (packageless classes works only in certain Tomcat+JDK combinations).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I do have these in packages, just was giving the smallest possible program.  What is the recommended approach to properly use MVC instead of the useBean?

Comment: The recommended way would be using an existing MVC framework which is designed on top of Servlet API like JSF, Spring MVC, etc. With plain JSP/Servlet you can get the idea in the examples and (tutorial) links in our servlets wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: sounds good thanks.  Just trying to establish the core underneath of it.

Comment: That's a perfect reason :) Understanding JSP/Servlets is mandatory before diving into MVC frameworks which are built on top of it.